# Making a connection to Rally with Ruby Toolkit for Rally REST API (rally_api)

Tags: ruby, rally

I'm trying to connect using the ruby API toolkit.
I followed the instructions in: https://developer.help.rallydev.com/ruby-toolkit-rally-rest-api-json
The script is exactly the same as the chapter "Making a connection to Rally" with my own values.
I receive the following error:

ruby test
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rally_api-0.9.14/lib/rally_api/rally_rest_json.rb:437: warning: don't put space before argument parentheses
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rally_api-0.9.14/lib/rally_api/rally_collection.rb:30:in `each': undefined method`parameters' for # (NoMethodError)
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rally_api-0.9.14/lib/rally_api/rally_rest_json.rb:104:in `find_workspace'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rally_api-0.9.14/lib/rally_api/rally_rest_json.rb:79:in`initialize'
        from test:19:in `new'
        from test:19

Any tips?

Comment: What ruby version are you running: ruby -v

Comment: It would also be helpful to know what Operating System and type (32, 64 bit), you are running. Please provide as much information as possible - the more info we have, the better we may be able to assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rally_api requires Ruby 1.9.2 or higher, so you'll need to upgrade your Ruby. I'd strongly recommend using RVM (Ruby Version Manager) to accomodate running an additional, higher-level ruby version on your system.

This article:

http://www.srcnix.com/tutorials/ruby/install-multiple-ruby-versions-on-ubuntu-12-04-using-rvm/

has a nice guide on installing and configuring RVM on Ubuntu 12.04.